# VC++ Directories seem not to be settable in Visual Studio Community 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include-path

Various resources indicate that #include paths can be added by editing the VC++ Directories in the property page for my project. The problem is, this option does not appear in my project.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've opened the solution's property page not the project's.

Comment: It's hard to keep them straight when there's a 1-1 correspondence, as there is in simple (default) solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. New to Visual Studio. I had the same problem